# How I can disable some tests in Travis CI for python

Tags: python, travis-ci

I would like to know. How I can disable some tests in Travis CI.
I am trying wrote something it but it didn't work

```
@pytest.mark.skipif("TRAVIS" in os.environ and os.environ["TRAVIS"] == "true", 
reason="Skipping this test on Travis CI.")
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_can_unwatch_remote_actor(remote_manager):
```

Answer (score 0):

In Travis configuration you can [add](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/) custom environment variable. 
For example you can add in your `.travis.yml` file this line

```
env: TRAVIS=true
```

then use it in `skipif`.

If you would like to test it locally and you work on UNIX like system (eg. Linux, MacOS) you can test it locally with

```
TRAVIS=true pytest ..
```

Comment: According to the documentation, this variable should be set by default, but isn't?
https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables

Comment: I do not remember if this variable is set by default when I'm writing this response. Maybe it Was missed this time. 

If you use `tox`, then You may need to add these variables to `passenv`.

Comment: This was indeed the issue for me. I think maybe it would be good to add a note about it in the reply? Anyway.. Migrating away from travis now, since I can no longer get free build credits.

Comment: You wrote about `passenv` or not set variable?